# Octal numbers in babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, octal

I'm playing with [`babel-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-cli). I installed the ES2015 extension and it works well. For example, the following snippet:

```
let square = x => x * x;
```

...is converted into:

```
"use strict";

var square = function square(x) {
  return x * x;
};
```

However I have trouble when using octal numbers. For example:

```
let mode = 0777;
```

throws me an error:

```
SyntaxError: index.js: Invalid number (1:11)
> 1 | let mode = 0777;
    |            ^

  2 |
```

It looks like it doesn't like the numbers starting with `0` (octal numbers). How can I solve this?

In fact, such numbers appear not in my code but in one of the dependencies.

Is it a babel bug or a feature? What is the workaround/solution?

Comment: When I try in my browser it says : "Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode."

Comment: You can't use octal numbers with strict mode. See point 2 [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-of-ecmascript)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! But then how to solve this since it's not my code? Looks it's fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp/commit/48e67fce39f1a5f2aba6196301b7be6d4545d6cf). It was coming from `mkdirp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing it incorrectly, it should be like `let mode = 0o777;`, notice the **o** between *0* and *777*

ES6 documentation here: [Binary and Octal Literals](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#binary-and-octal-literals)

```js
// try this in chrome
document.write(0o777);
```

Comment: Oh, interesting! I didn't know that! Looks like it's working. But since this is not my code, is there any hope to get it working by using some workaround?

Comment: Babel recognizes it like this, but browsers like chrome work in a loose validation mode, and 0777 works like 0o777 in chrome, but that is not a standard, and will fail at different platforms, so all the good codes should follow the standard. The standard is mentioned here: https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#binary-and-octal-literals

Comment: `0777` works in JS engines in non-strict-mode, but Babel code is strict by default.